# How to set backround image without cropping on different sizes of displays?

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

i'm developing simple HTML5 game for mobile devices using Cordova.

I faced with problem with positioning of the game objects on different resolutions of displays.

Objects are placed relatively to left || right and top position.

But background image has some places which are used a place for placing and moving the game object (for example spired is moving on the net)..see image below[image]

It means that on some devices is spider "out" of the net because background image is cropped. I would like to have visible same part of the background on all devices (from left to right and from top (bottom is not important because no object is positioned against the bottom and missing background should be filled using the black color)).

How can i do it please?

**Actual code for the background is following:**

```
.gameBgImage {
    background: url("../img/objects/bg_game.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**Viewport tag isset to:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

Many thanks fro any advice

Comment: Is it possible for you to just composite all the images into one?

Comment: No , is not because the spiders are moving on the net and windows, candles are burning in the windows, etc..(not all objects are placed in screenshots).

Answer (score 0):

Set background-size to 100%. It will adjust the horizontal size so that it fits, so both left and right corners will be in visible.

set background-color to black so that the bottom part will be that color if the display ratio needs it